# SQL $wpdb->get_results() ORDER BY different from phpmyadmin sql query (umlaute)

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have some code in an old wordpress script:

```
$qs = "SELECT * FROM test";
$qs .= "ORDER BY name, beginn, ende";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($qs, OBJECT);
```

Output order for name:

U V W X Ü Y Z

If i do the same query in phpmyadmin "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY name, beginn, ende;"

Output order for name:

Ü U V W X Y Z  (this is the result i want)

Why does "$wpdb->get_results" change the result?

Comment: I suppose that when connecting to the DBMS, you can set a default collation, i.e. the language that shall be used when comapring and sorting strings. It seems that wordpress sets a collation different from the one you want. But well, that's just guessing.

Comment: Check wp-config.php and 'define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' )' row for potential confict with desired collation.